# Проверка на дублирование БД

Tags: php, html, mysql

Создаю html форму в которой элементы выпадающего списка будут данные из столбца в нашей таблице. Пример кода:

```
            <form action="/result" method="POST">
                Country: 
                <select>
                    <?php
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT country FROM speakers ");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    ?>
                    <?php 
                    <option><?php echo $row['country']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>               
            </form>
```

И в том случае если данные повторяются получается следующее:

```
<select>
<option>Russia</option>
<option>Poland</option>
<option>Russia</option>
</select>
```

Как сделать что бы значение не повторялись?

Comment: Наоборот таблица содержит всю необходимую мне информацию. А этот метод мне помогает в дальнейшем найти все необходимые данные с этими значениями

Comment: Для расширенного поиска.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    country 
FROM speakers
```